# Does she say "nodding off" or "nodding no"?

Tags: listening

During this clip, [at 1:24](https://youtu.be/W-ZdQ0z5cLM) is she saying

> I went from nodding no to nodding yes...

Or does she say "nodding off"? Because I don't think you can nod no, can you?

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think you can nod "no", at least in places where "nodding" is used for agreement. In the US, nodding is used for agreement.

> [nod](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nodding+off)
>
> - To lower and raise (the head) quickly in agreement or acknowledgment.
> - A forward or up-and-down movement of the head, usually expressive of drowsiness or agreement

The speaker says

> I went from nodding off to nodding yes to more heroin.

*Nod off* means

> [nod off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nodding+off)
>   To doze momentarily:
>   *nodded off during the lecture.*

So the joke uses a small play on words. *Nodding yes* suggests that she became more active or alert.

**Fun fact.** You [***shake***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shake) your head in disagreement.

Comment: In some Arab cultures, a sideways waggle (similar to a shake) of the head, which might be interpreted as a negative in Europe and the Americas, means YES; whereas a quick down-to-up movement of the head, which might be interpreted as an affirmative in Europe and the Americas, means NO!